# How does the dimension of two subspaces relate to their intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^8$ such that $\dim\, U=3$, $\dim\, V=5$, and $U \cup V=\mathbb R^8$. Prove that $U\oplus V=\mathbb R^8$.

My question is:
How can I, or if I should, use the dimension of $U$ and $V$ to show that their intersection is empty?

Comment: Intersection is not empty. It Just have the zero element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formula should help:
$$
\dim(U + V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U \cap V).
$$
What can you conclude about $\dim(U \cap V)$? What does that imply about $U \oplus V$?

Comment: P.S. Just a random aside, but the analogous statement for three vector spaces ($\dim(U + V + W) = \cdots$) is not true; see [this famous MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23501#23501).